# Robot Framework - How to refer a button ID which changes frequently?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I have a sign in page, in which the id of the sign-in button changes. The id can either one of the two.

```
id = signin
or
id = signin_cache1
```

The id is assigned in Java based on the math.random() function. The statement is,

```
num = (int)(math.random() * 100)
if num < 50 id=signin
if num > 50 id=signin_cache1
```

My robot framework with selenium2library script fails, if the id is different from the one I coded in the script. Is there a way in robot framework to refer both ids so that my script never fails?

Comment: Potential Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159680/how-to-handle-dynamic-elements-using-robot-framework/41160640#41160640
You basically need to use Xpaths :)

Comment: have you tried simply looking for one, and if it fails, look for the other? The other solution is to tell your developers this is a dumb idea (unless the alternate id is required for some other purpose you can't control).

Answer (score 2):

How about `css=#signin, #signin_cache1` or `css=[id^="signin"]`?

The first is a selector that matches all elements with id "signin" and all elements with id "signin_cache1". The second selector looks up all elements with an id attribute which starts with "signin".

(I'm only guessing since I only know Selenium 2 / WebDriver and haven't worked with the Robot Framework yet. The documentation for it seems to be very fragmented.)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to run the script n number of times with the first css code in the script!